# How to Delete contents of file using swift 4.0 language

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift2, xcode9

I would just like to know the code to delete the contents of the existing file in a directory

Comment: You don't just want to delete the file? You want to end up with an empty file instead?

Answer (score 0):

As you would usually do in every programming language - create a new empty file by overwriting the old one.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an URL to the file, you can simply replace the contents of it with an empty string:

**Swift 2**

```
do {
    try "".writeToURL(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

**Swift 3+**

```
do {
    try "".write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Read more about `write(toFile:atomically:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1408033-write).

Comment: this is wrong. If you set atomically to false it will not overwrite the file